# Flutter - The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0 && Build input file cannot be found GoogleService-Info.plist

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-simulator, simulator

I cannot build a Flutter app on iOS simulator. I am getting this error over and over. My flutter-doctor is clean.

```
 Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (2nd generation) in debug mode...
    Xcode build done.                                           26,7s
    Failed to build iOS app
    Error output from Xcode build:
    ↳
        ** BUILD FAILED **
    Xcode's output:
    ↳
        error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/User/Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist' (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
        note: Using new build system
        note: Building targets in parallel
        note: Planning build
        note: Constructing build description
        warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'AppAuth' from project 'Pods')
        warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'GTMAppAuth' from project 'Pods')
        warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
        warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
        warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 5.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
        warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp' from project 'Pods')
        warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 4.3, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
        warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'GTMSessionFetcher' from project 'Pods')
        warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
        warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
    Could not build the application for the simulator.
    Error launching application on iPhone SE (2nd generation).
    Exited (sigterm)
```

[image: Flutter doctor]

Answer (score 49, accepted):

To get rid of this warning:

```
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'AppAuth' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'GTMAppAuth' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 5.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 4.3, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'GTMSessionFetcher' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
```

Make sure your **Podfile** contains this line

**config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'**

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
    end
  end
end
```

To make the app build successfully and get rid of:

```
error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/User/Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist' (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

remove and add again **through Xcode**, the GoogleService-Info.plist file.

Comment: When I do this... I am now getting - In file included from /Users/mridley/_development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/package_info-0.4.3+2/ios/Classes/FLTPackageInfoPlugin.m:5:
    /Users/mridley/_development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/package_info-0.4.3+2/ios/Classes/FLTPackageInfoPlugin.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found - Any ideas?

Comment: @RiddlerDev run 'flutter pub cache repair & flutter clean & cd ios & pod deintegrate & flutter pub get' then run the app once again

Comment: @RiddlerDev for flutter apps, `flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)` should be added after line `installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|` otherwise you get the `'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found` error.

Answer (score 7):

A little improvement to maxpills answer

```
post_install do |installer|

  puts 'Determining pod project minimal deployment target'

  pods_project = installer.pods_project
  deployment_target_key = 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
  deployment_targets = pods_project.build_configurations.map{ |config| config.build_settings[deployment_target_key] }
  minimal_deployment_target = deployment_targets.min_by{ |version| Gem::Version.new(version) }

  puts 'Minimal deployment target is ' + minimal_deployment_target
  puts 'Setting each pod deployment target to ' + minimal_deployment_target

  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings[deployment_target_key] = minimal_deployment_target
    end
  end
end
```

This is using the target version defined at the start of the Podfile

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
```

Comment: You have one line in there that says `'DEBUG=1']` Is this somehow a copy paste error? :)

Comment: for sure it is @p0wl

Comment: So the real question is: Is there half a line missing or should I just remove the `'DEBUG=1']`?

Comment: Can you please fix the syntax errors in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Project Document in attributes inspector highlighted]

1. Open Xcode
2. Change Project Document -> Project format -> Xcode 8.0-Compatible
3. `flutter clean`, `flutter pub` get an flutter build iOS

Answer (score 2):

For me it was set to 8.0 in the highlighted field here in XCode, setting it to 10 fixed it for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I revised @Hons answer a little to resolve issues I was having using both the [OneSignal](https://pub.dev/packages/onesignal_flutter) and [uni_links 0.5.1](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links) packages with Xcode 12.5.

Edit the `./ios/Podspec` file, uncomment the second line of file (and update with minimim target version):

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'
```

and then replace the target code for OneSignal and post_install script with:

```
target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '3.2.1'
end

post_install do |installer|
  puts 'Determining pod project minimal deployment target'
  pods_project = installer.pods_project
  deployment_target_key = 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
  deployment_targets = pods_project.build_configurations.map{ |config| config.build_settings[deployment_target_key] }
  minimal_deployment_target = deployment_targets.min_by{ |version| Gem::Version.new(version) }
  puts 'Minimal deployment target is ' + minimal_deployment_target
  puts 'Setting each pod deployment target to ' + minimal_deployment_target
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings[deployment_target_key] = minimal_deployment_target
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```