# IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET does not match with deployment target of libraries in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I changed every deployment target in Podfile, AppFrameworkInfo.plist, Runner and Target in Xcode but having issue with ios deployment target. Before posting files, I double check deployment infos in Target Runner and Project Runner and all of them set to iOS 10.0

This is the error

```
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment
target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'url_launcher' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment
target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'unity_ads_plugin' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment
target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'shared_preferences' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment
target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'qr_code_scanner' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment
target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'path_provider' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment
target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment
target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment
target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment
target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment
target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment
target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'fluttertoast' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment
target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'flutter_secure_storage' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment
target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'flutter_local_notifications' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment
target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'flutter_inappwebview' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment
target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'firebase_messaging' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment
target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'device_info' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment
target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'connectivity' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment
target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'assets_audio_player_web' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment
target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'assets_audio_player' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment
target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment
target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'Toast' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment
target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'Reachability' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment
target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'MTBBarcodeScanner' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment
target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment
target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment
target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
```

This is my podfile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.0'
    end
  end
end
```

This is my AppFrameworkInfo.plist file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
  <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
  <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
  <string>App</string>
  <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
  <string>io.flutter.flutter.app</string>
  <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
  <string>6.0</string>
  <key>CFBundleName</key>
  <string>App</string>
  <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
  <string>FMWK</string>
  <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
  <string>1.0</string>
  <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
  <string>????</string>
  <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
  <string>1.0</string>
  <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
  <string>10.0</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I'm getting tired and I could not find a solution almost for a week. I do not know what is wrong with the configuration settings but is anyone really can explain why this happens and how to solve it?

Comment: let me know if this solution worked ??

Answer (score 0):

open android studio search `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` and set the target at all places to `10` I will worked as it also worked for me also

Comment: All of these fields already were set to 10.

Comment: can i check through teamviewer ??

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Podfile contains this line

config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
    end
  end
end
```

for more detail please click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61823611/11427294)