# Why am I getting this deployment target warning in my Flutter Project in Android Studio?

Tags: xcode, flutter, android-studio

The **Error** I am getting:

```
fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete

warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

I also checked the Podfile
the **platform:ios** is set to `'9.0'`.

I also tried updating and configuring the **Podfile**, but still the same errors and warnings are popping up.

Comment: You can try the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61823611/10488444