# How to fix "Concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer" error Flutter

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, flutter-ios

I recently updated my Flutter SDK to 3.0.4, and my project would no longer build when trying to launch on the iOS Simulator.

I got the following errors and implemented the solutions below each error:

```
The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99.
```

Solution that has worked in the past but fails now since this is also included in the error message: [Flutter - The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0 && Build input file cannot be found GoogleService-Info.plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61823044/flutter-the-ios-simulator-deployment-target-iphoneos-deployment-target-is-se)

and

```
error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
```

Solution when I got above error, worked in the past, not now: [error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found when flutter run on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973346/error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found-when-flutter-run-on-ios) (basically deleting and rebuilding ios folder)

I then tried to re-implement this (https://codewithandrea.com/tips/speed-up-cloud-firestore-xcode-builds/) after rebuilding the ios folder (requires a new podfile) in the solution above as the builds took forever to fail, and it worked well before the Flutter update. I used firestore version 9.2.0 since that is what was in my podfile.lock file.

This is when I started getting the swift compiler error I cannot solve, shown below. Other projects are running with the flutter update and on this simulator. Even after reversing the solution from the "code with Andrea" link above, I still get this same error.

pod install, pod update, flutter pub cache repair, flutter clean, flutter pub get, pod install --repo-update, none of these solve the error.

Please help.

Error message (it wouldn't let me post the whole thing, character limits):

```
Running "flutter pub get" in project_name...
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 in debug mode...
Xcode build done.                                           300.1s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/5m/btwjgwbs3zz4xt0v29h78lsm0000gn/T/flutter_tools.GaL813/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirDysItT/temporary_xcresult_bundle
/Users/user1/development/tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-4.4.0/ios/Classes/LocationPlugin.m:176:13: warning: 'UIAlertView' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location is Disabled"
                ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/location/location-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAlertView.h:27:12: note: 'UIAlertView' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface UIAlertView : UIView
               ^
/Users/user1/development/tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-4.4.0/ios/Classes/LocationPlugin.m:176:48: warning: 'UIAlertView' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location is Disabled"
                                                   ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/location/location-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAlertView.h:27:12: note: 'UIAlertView' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface UIAlertView : UIView
               ^
    2 warnings generated.
/Users/user1/development/tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-4.4.0/ios/Classes/LocationPlugin.m:176:13: warning: 'UIAlertView' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location is Disabled"
                ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/location/location-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAlertView.h:27:12: note: 'UIAlertView' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface UIAlertView : UIView
               ^
/Users/user1/development/tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-4.4.0/ios/Classes/LocationPlugin.m:176:48: warning: 'UIAlertView' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location is Disabled"
                                                   ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/location/location-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAlertView.h:27:12: note: 'UIAlertView' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface UIAlertView : UIView
               ^
    2 warnings generated.
    1 warning generated.
    error: the following command failed with exit code 0 but produced no further output
CompileC /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-btumkhqxnfgahyertjizuikcyuzl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/geolocator_apple.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GeolocatorPlugin.o /Users/user1/development/tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator_apple-2.2.0/ios/Classes/GeolocatorPlugin.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'geolocator_apple' from project 'Pods')
/Users/user1/development/tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/connectivity_plus-2.3.5/ios/Classes/ReachabilityConnectivityProvider.swift:23:5: warning: result of call to 'ensureReachability()' is unused
        ensureReachability()
        ^                 ~~
/Users/user1/development/tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/connectivity_plus-2.3.5/ios/Classes/PathMonitorConnectivityProvider.swift:31:5: warning: result of call to 'ensurePathMonitor()' is unused
        ensurePathMonitor()
        ^                ~~
/Users/user1/development/tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/connectivity_plus-2.3.5/ios/Classes/PathMonitorConnectivityProvider.swift:35:5: warning: result of call to 'ensurePathMonitor()' is unused
        ensurePathMonitor()
        ^                ~~
/Users/user1/development/tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/connectivity_plus-2.3.5/ios/Classes/PathMonitorConnectivityProvider.swift:31:5: warning: result of call to 'ensurePathMonitor()' is unused
        ensurePathMonitor()
        ^                ~~
/Users/user1/development/tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/connectivity_plus-2.3.5/ios/Classes/PathMonitorConnectivityProvider.swift:35:5: warning: result of call to 'ensurePathMonitor()' is unused
        ensurePathMonitor()
        ^                ~~
/Users/user1/development/tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/connectivity_plus-2.3.5/ios/Classes/ReachabilityConnectivityProvider.swift:23:5: warning: result of call to 'ensureReachability()' is unused
        ensureReachability()
        ^                 ~~
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:224:29: error: concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer
        open func downloadURL() async throws -> URL {
                                ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:25:39: note: add @available attribute to enclosing class
    @objc(FIRStorageReference) open class StorageReference: NSObject {
                                          ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:293:25: error: concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer
        open func listAll() async throws -> StorageListResult {
                            ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:25:39: note: add @available attribute to enclosing class
    @objc(FIRStorageReference) open class StorageReference: NSObject {
                                          ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:377:29: error: concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer
        open func getMetadata() async throws -> StorageMetadata {
                                ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:25:39: note: add @available attribute to enclosing class
    @objc(FIRStorageReference) open class StorageReference: NSObject {
                                          ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:407:59: error: concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer
        open func updateMetadata(_ metadata: StorageMetadata) async throws -> StorageMetadata {
                                                              ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:25:39: note: add @available attribute to enclosing class
    @objc(FIRStorageReference) open class StorageReference: NSObject {
                                          ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:441:24: error: concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer
        open func delete() async throws {
                           ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:25:39: note: add @available attribute to enclosing class
    @objc(FIRStorageReference) open class StorageReference: NSObject {
                                          ^
    /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-btumkhqxnfgahyertjizuikcyuzl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseStorage.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/StorageMetadata.dia:1:1: warning: Could not read serialized diagnostics file: error("Invalid diagnostics signature") (in target 'FirebaseStorage' from project 'Pods')
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:224:29: error: concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer
        open func downloadURL() async throws -> URL {
                                ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:25:39: note: add @available attribute to enclosing class
    @objc(FIRStorageReference) open class StorageReference: NSObject {
                                          ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:293:25: error: concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer
        open func listAll() async throws -> StorageListResult {
                            ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:25:39: note: add @available attribute to enclosing class
    @objc(FIRStorageReference) open class StorageReference: NSObject {
                                          ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:377:29: error: concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer
        open func getMetadata() async throws -> StorageMetadata {
                                ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:25:39: note: add @available attribute to enclosing class
    @objc(FIRStorageReference) open class StorageReference: NSObject {
                                          ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:407:59: error: concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer
        open func updateMetadata(_ metadata: StorageMetadata) async throws -> StorageMetadata {
                                                              ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:25:39: note: add @available attribute to enclosing class
    @objc(FIRStorageReference) open class StorageReference: NSObject {
                                          ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:441:24: error: concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer
        open func delete() async throws {
                           ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:25:39: note: add @available attribute to enclosing class
    @objc(FIRStorageReference) open class StorageReference: NSObject {
                                          ^
    /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-btumkhqxnfgahyertjizuikcyuzl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseStorage.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/StorageObservableTask.dia:1:1: warning: Could not read serialized diagnostics file: error("Invalid diagnostics signature") (in target 'FirebaseStorage' from project 'Pods')
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:224:29: error: concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer
        open func downloadURL() async throws -> URL {
                                ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:25:39: note: add @available attribute to enclosing class
    @objc(FIRStorageReference) open class StorageReference: NSObject {
                                          ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:293:25: error: concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer
        open func listAll() async throws -> StorageListResult {
                            ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:25:39: note: add @available attribute to enclosing class
    @objc(FIRStorageReference) open class StorageReference: NSObject {
                                          ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:377:29: error: concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer
        open func getMetadata() async throws -> StorageMetadata {
                                ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:25:39: note: add @available attribute to enclosing class
    @objc(FIRStorageReference) open class StorageReference: NSObject {
                                          ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:407:59: error: concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer
        open func updateMetadata(_ metadata: StorageMetadata) async throws -> StorageMetadata {
                                                              ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:25:39: note: add @available attribute to enclosing class
    @objc(FIRStorageReference) open class StorageReference: NSObject {
                                          ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:441:24: error: concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer
        open func delete() async throws {
                           ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:25:39: note: add @available attribute to enclosing class
    @objc(FIRStorageReference) open class StorageReference: NSObject {
                                          ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:224:29: error: concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer
        open func downloadURL() async throws -> URL {
                                ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:25:39: note: add @available attribute to enclosing class
    @objc(FIRStorageReference) open class StorageReference: NSObject {
                                          ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:293:25: error: concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer
        open func listAll() async throws -> StorageListResult {
                            ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:25:39: note: add @available attribute to enclosing class
    @objc(FIRStorageReference) open class StorageReference: NSObject {
                                          ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:377:29: error: concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer
        open func getMetadata() async throws -> StorageMetadata {
                                ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:25:39: note: add @available attribute to enclosing class
    @objc(FIRStorageReference) open class StorageReference: NSObject {
                                          ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:407:59: error: concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer
        open func updateMetadata(_ metadata: StorageMetadata) async throws -> StorageMetadata {
                                                              ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:25:39: note: add @available attribute to enclosing class
    @objc(FIRStorageReference) open class StorageReference: NSObject {
                                          ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:441:24: error: concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer
        open func delete() async throws {
                           ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:25:39: note: add @available attribute to enclosing class
    @objc(FIRStorageReference) open class StorageReference: NSObject {
                                          ^
    /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-btumkhqxnfgahyertjizuikcyuzl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseStorage.build/Objects-normal/i386/StorageMetadata.dia:1:1: warning: Could not read serialized diagnostics file: error("Invalid diagnostics signature") (in target 'FirebaseStorage' from project 'Pods')
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
                                          ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:407:59: error: concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer
        open func updateMetadata(_ metadata: StorageMetadata) async throws -> StorageMetadata {
                                                              ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:25:39: note: add @available attribute to enclosing class
    @objc(FIRStorageReference) open class StorageReference: NSObject {
                                          ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:441:24: error: concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer
        open func delete() async throws {
                           ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:25:39: note: add @available attribute to enclosing class
    @objc(FIRStorageReference) open class StorageReference: NSObject {
                                          ^
    /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-btumkhqxnfgahyertjizuikcyuzl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseStorage.build/Objects-normal/arm64/StorageMetadata.dia:1:1: warning: Could not read serialized diagnostics file: error("Invalid diagnostics signature") (in target 'FirebaseStorage' from project 'Pods')
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code                                ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:25:39: note: add @available attribute to enclosing class
    @objc(FIRStorageReference) open class StorageReference: NSObject {
                                          ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:407:59: error: concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer
        open func updateMetadata(_ metadata: StorageMetadata) async throws -> StorageMetadata {
                                                              ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:25:39: note: add @available attribute to enclosing class
    @objc(FIRStorageReference) open class StorageReference: NSObject {
                                          ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:441:24: error: concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer
        open func delete() async throws {
                           ^
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:25:39: note: add @available attribute to enclosing class
    @objc(FIRStorageReference) open class StorageReference: NSObject {
                                          ^
    Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Removed stale file '/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-btumkhqxnfgahyertjizuikcyuzl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/firebase_core/firebase_core.framework'
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'ReachabilitySwift' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'MTBBarcodeScanner' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController-TOCropViewControllerBundle' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/5m/btwjgwbs3zz4xt0v29h78lsm0000gn/T/flutter_tools.GaL813/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirDysItT/temporary_xcresult_bundle
Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer
/Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:223:28
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer
/Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:292:24
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer
/Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:376:28
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer
/Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:406:58
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer
/Users/projectPath/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:440:23
Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12.
Exited
```

Comment: I came across this link https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/681782 which has this comment: "Point and click method: In Xcode 13 beta 1, you can click on the compile time error for "*** is only available in iOS 15.0 or newer" over on the right hand side, the red error button. Red dialog opens, scroll down to "Add available attribute to enclosing struct" click fix, done. Thanks @ihaze for helping me figure this out." Is this a bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

[image: preview]In you podfile. Check the platform version uncomment it and change it to 11. Also open the runner.xcworkspace in xcode. You will see warnings ontop. Click on those warnings and click on perform charges. And run the project from Xcode once

**EDIT**

If you click on the icon that's marked in red. It should open the warning on the left pane. Select each one and it will show a pop up to resolve versions.

Also execute `pod install --repo-update` and try once

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The platform version is already uncommented and set to 11, didn't have character space to include the podfile in the question. Where do you see the warnings and the perform changes? Maybe you can include a screenshot?

Comment: Edited my answer and added a screenshot

Comment: Thanks for your help! Didn't need to do that, turns out I just needed to update XCode and the error is gone now.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this issue was caused by XCode. Uninstalling and reinstalling the most recent version solved it for me