# Flutter Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h' file not found

Tags: ios, flutter, google-maps, cocoapods

After I updated flutter to the latest version I keep getting this error for **GoogleMobileAds** and **GoogleMaps**

When I try to `flutter build ios` I get the same error
`Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h' file not found /Users/.../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/google_maps_flutter_ios-2.3.1/ios/Classes/GoogleMa pPolylineController.h:5:8`

`Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h' file not found /Users/.../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/google_mobile_ads-4.0.0/ios/Clas ses/NativeTemplates/GoogleAdsMobileIosNativeTemplates/GADTTemplateView.h:14: 8`

(Depending which package is found in the pubspec)

System

- macOS: 13.5.1
- xCode:  15.2
- Flutter version 3.19.1
- Dart version 3.3.0
- CocoaPods version 1.15.1

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.1, on macOS 13.5.1 22G90 darwin-arm64,
    locale en-GR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.86.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources
```

In the project I first encountered this issue has a lot of packages but at first I was using
google_mobile_ads: ^2.3.0

Many suggested to try on a new project but no luck there I get the same issue, I also tried one of the examples from the google ads repo and I get the same issue...
I even tried from Codemagic to build my app and again I get the same issue...

I have also tried:

- playing with lower versions of the 2 packages
- `rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock`
- `pod cache clean --all` along with `flutter pub cache clean`
- Add the 2 packages in the Podfile
- deintegrate pods and install/update

I have been searching for a solution for over 2 weeks now this is becoming extremely frustrating, please help me out on this. Below is my podfile and the dependencies of my pubspec.

### Podfile

```rb
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '14.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  pod 'MLKitVision', :podspec => 'MLKitVision.podspec.json'
  pod 'MLKitCommon', :podspec => 'MLKitCommon.podspec.json'

  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  # Ensure pods also use the minimum deployment target set above
  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/64385584/436422
  puts 'Determining pod project minimum deployment target'

  pods_project = installer.pods_project
  deployment_target_key = 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
  deployment_targets = pods_project.build_configurations.map{ |config| config.build_settings[deployment_target_key] }
  minimum_deployment_target = deployment_targets.min_by{ |version| Gem::Version.new(version) }

  puts 'Minimal deployment target is ' + minimum_deployment_target
  puts 'Setting each pod deployment target to ' + minimum_deployment_target

  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      #config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
      config.build_settings[deployment_target_key] = minimum_deployment_target
    end
  end
end
```

### Dependencies from pubspec.yaml

I left some other google packages just in case that might have to do anything with my problem because I face the same issue with google maps

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.4 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_riverpod:

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^2.7.1
  firebase_auth: ^4.6.3
  cloud_firestore: ^4.8.2
  firebase_messaging: ^14.2.6
  firebase_analytics: ^10.1.5
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.0.16
  connectivity_plus: ^3.0.3
  intl: any
  google_fonts: ^4.0.3
  firebase_storage: ^11.0.16
  google_sign_in: ^6.1.5
  bloc: ^8.1.1
  equatable: ^2.0.5
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.2
  ...
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.5.3
  geolocator: ^9.0.2
  geocoding: ^2.1.0
  firebase_ui_firestore: ^1.5.6
  google_mobile_ads: 4.0.0

flutter_launcher_icons:
...


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  mockito: ^5.4.2
  build_runner: ^2.4.6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting in hopes that one day this might help someone out. I ended up deleting from my MacBook the pub cache and cocoa pods completely from the device and then re installing them. Once I had done that my app worked fine again.